# I am trying to make a program that takes 10 integers as input in array. But when I run it, it closes after the first input. New to programming

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int a[10]; //array declaration
    printf("Enter 10 numbers: "); 

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) //loop to take input
    {
        scanf("%d", (a[i]));
    }

}
```

Trying to make a program in C that takes 10 integers in an array "a". But it closes after taking the first input. What can be the error?

Comment: Please change `(a[i])` to `&a[i]` and pay attention to compiler warnings!

Comment: Save time, enable _all_ compiler warnings.

Comment: Can I ask a question why we answer in comments ? should not we answer to this question?

Comment: regarding: `main()`  This was 'ok' for a 1980s C code. Strongly suggest using a 'modern' valid signature like: `int main( void )`

Comment: Regarding: `printf("Enter 10 numbers: ");`  this does NOT tell the user how to enter the numbers.  Suggest: `printf("Enter 10 numbers, separated by newlines and/or spaces:\n");

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%d", (a[i]));` 1)  the `scanf()` family of functions parameters MUST be pointers to the target variable.  2) for robust code, always check the returned value.  Note: those functions return a count of the number of successful 'input format conversion' specifiers (or EOF).  For the current scenario, suggest: `if( scanf( "%d", &a[i] ) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for input number failed\n" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use &a[i] to take input. As we need to pass variable address to take input value from user.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int a[10]; 
 printf("Enter 10 numbers: "); 

  for(int i=0;i<10;i++) 
  {
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
  }
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: This answer does not cleanly compile.  This statement: `main()` causes the compiler to output a message about the return type.  Note: Many years ago, a return type of `int` was assumed, but not today

Comment: It's void by default

Comment: ALL compilers that are compliant to the C programming standard have `int` as the only valid return type from `main()`